# Does this 希望能帮得你 have the same meaning as 希望有帮上你的忙?

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms

Within the context of this:
谢谢你，你真是帮了大忙。  This line was from a native speaker.

不客气， 希望有帮上你的忙。  This line was also from a native speaker.
不客气， 希望能帮得你。  This is the one I formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 不客气， 希望能帮得你。

The sentence you made is incorrect. It should be 希望能帮***到***你. So you misused 得 here.

The other sentences are fine.

Answer (score 0):

A small modification can make your sentence the same as spoken by a native:

不客气， 希望能帮得**了**(liǎo)你.

I don't like the second sentence. It would be better if if "你的" is eliminated, then 希望有帮上忙 is fine. You can also modify your sentence as:

不客气， 希望能帮得**上**你.

**ADD:** You need to know the occasion to use each of the sentences:

- 希望有(have)帮上忙 - The matter was behind, and you have provided help to resolve it.
- 希望能(can)帮得上你 - The matter is ongoing, and you are willing to offer help.